# Padrino custom log file

Tags: ruby, padrino

I need to create a custom log file within Padrino that contains all of the logging information that is in stdout as well as custom log messages. I have been able to get the custom log file created, but the stdout file (development.log, production.log, etc.) still gets created with logging statements in it. I have tried putting these lines in the boot.rb file, but none of these seem to work:

```
Padrino::Logger::Config[:development][:stream] = :to_file

Padrino::Logger::Config[:development] = { :log_level => :debug, :stream => :to_file }

Padrino::Logger::Config[:development][:stream] = :null

Padrino::Logger::Config[:development] = { :log_level => :debug, :stream => :null}
```

I have looked at Padrino's [development commands](http://www.padrinorb.com/guides/development-commands) and [logger documentation](http://www.padrinorb.com/api/Padrino/Logger.html) but they didn't help.

In case it helps, this is the code that is generating the custom log file. (Whether I run this code or not, the stdout file keeps getting created):

```
log_path = File.join(custom_log_path, 'My Service')

FileUtils.mkdir_p log_path
log_file_path = File.join(log_path, "MyService_#{current_date_time_formatted}.log")
logger = File.open(log_file_path, "a+")

if defined?(PADRINO_ENV) && PADRINO_ENV == 'production'
  $stdout.reopen(logger)
  $stderr.reopen(logger)
end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you do logger configuration before `Padrino.before_load do` or inside of it?

Comment: @ujifgc I do the configuration before `Padrino.before_load do`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
Padrino::Logger::Config[:development][:stream] = logger
# or
Padrino::Logger::Config[:production][:stream] = logger
```

after you have defined `logger`. If `config[:stream]` doesn't receive a keyword, `Padrino::Logger` will use whatever is passed as the output stream.

For more information on the Padrino logger, check out the relevant Padrino Core code, especially `self.setup!`: https://github.com/padrino/padrino-framework/blob/master/padrino-core/lib/padrino-core/logger.rb.

Comment: That doesn't work. It still creates both the stdout log file and my custom one. I had looked at that Padrino Core code too and it seems like what you had suggested should work but for some reason it still doesn't.

Comment: Something else must be creating the stdout log because I put the same code as above in the "sample_blog" application from Padrino's site and it does what we'd expect it to do. It creates only my custom log file.

Comment: The padrino application that I was having an issue with is being run via Trinidad, so I believe that is what is creating the stdout log file. I'm doing some testing and will post an update as soon as I get results.

Comment: It was Trinidad that was creating the additional log file. As a test I commented out some of the code in Trinidad's logging.rb file and the extra log file is no longer created.